# DataGridView out of memory?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Guys I am trying to load 2 million rows at once in a C# winforms `DataGridView` but I am getting  `System.OutOfMemoryException`. Now my system has a 4 GB RAM (core2duo 2.4ghz) and the system memory consumption reaches at 67% max when loading the `DataGridView` (observed through task manager) and the application throws this exception.

Why is that? Can't `DataGridView` handle 2 million rows at once? or is my PC not capable ?

P.S. I am just using this for **testing purposes** and I know about pagination so please don't ask me why I am trying to load all the rows at once.

Code for generating test rows in `DataGridView` :-

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   dt.Columns.Add(i.ToString());
}
for (int j = 0; j < 2000000; j++)
{
   DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
   for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
   {
      row[k] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
   }
   dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: This might be of interest to you: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/155892/practical-size-limits-of-a-datatable-in-c

Comment: @user3331470 Well I recently found myself putting 9000 lines of code into a `DataGridView` for a little Mercurial diff tool I was making and found performance was terrible. So I [virtualized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode(v=vs.110).aspx) it. Perhaps look into doing that. I'd also review if you can do it without a `DataTable`, perhaps a simple `List<T>` instead?

Comment: Upon running performance analysis in VS12, I got this error which seems to be the cause :

DA0018: (Maximum)# Bytes in all Heaps = 1,643,798,088.00; Managed memory allocations approaching the default limit for a 32-bit process. Your application may be memory-bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because 32 bit applications are limited to approximately 1.6 gb of RAM, so if your `DataGridView` consumes more than that, your application is bound to crash.

Answer (score 0):

you are storing the guids as strings in your datatable which makes them quite big ... I guess if you would create guid columns you would not get into trouble ...